# How to use deftype to implement an associative structure in Clojurescript

Tags: protocols, clojurescript

I would like to provide a Clojurescript implementation of vector based on [Javascript Typed Arrays](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/), which supports assoc, replace etc. I think I want to do that (maybe there's a better way, or maybe someone's done it ?). Presumably I'd use deftype, but what protocols should I provide "concretions" for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what the built-in vectors implement. You can view the source [here, on github](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L2948).

Looks like it's: `Object`, `IWithMeta`, `IMeta`, `IStack`, `ICollection`, `IEmptyableCollection`, `ISequential`, `IEquiv`, `IHash`, `ISeqable`, `ICounted`, `IIndexed`, `ILookup`, `IMapEntry`, `IAssociative`, `IVector`, `IReduce`, `IKVReduce`, `IFn`, `IEditableCollection` and `IReversible`.

That's a lot, but since each one defines one or at most two methods, it isn't that much work. Plus, you could leave some of them unimplemented, like `IEditableCollection` which is only used for transients or `IReduce` which is for the new reducers functions.

You don't even have to make your new data structure work exactly like a built-in Vector, either. You could have it implement all the sequential stuff and not worry about the map stuff, for example, though of course then it would be less convenient than a normal Vector.